# Batch Script - Delete Columns in csv

Tags: csv, batch-file

I do need a batch script who will remove all columns in a csv, except column 1,2 and 5

My Code:

```
(for /f "tokens=1,2,5 delims=;" %%i in (Input.csv) do echo %%i,%%j,%%k) > Output.csv
```

Input CSV

```
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10
10160;"Some Name";"Something:0.8";;5;;;;;XY
```

Expected Output:

```
1;2;5
10160;"Some Name";5
```

Real Output

```
1,2,5
10160,"Some Name",XY
```

Does anyone have any idea why it keeps the tenth column in the second line instead of the fifth?

Comment: Well, you will not get `;` in the output file on using `,` in `echo %%i,%%j,%%k`. And it is true that `for /F` interprets a __series of delimiters__ as one delimiter. For that reason it is in general better to do such tasks with PowerShell and not with a batch file as PowerShell has true CSV file support. However, look on the results of a Stack Overflow search with [\[batch-file\] CSV empty value*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+CSV+empty+value*) and you will find the very inefficient solution in comparison doing that with PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

(FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN (Input.csv) DO SET "line=%%b"&SET "line=!line:;;=; ;!"&for /f "tokens=1,2,5 delims=;" %%i in ("!line:;;=; ;!") do echo %%i,%%j,%%k)
```

The problem is that a sequence of delimiters is considered as a single delimiter, so you need to change each delimiter pair so that it contains a string, and repeat the operation for any remaining delimiter-pairs.

Obviously, you would need to take action to take care of a reported field that now contains a single space, and this will alter any quoted field that contains `;;`

Note also that any data containing `!` or `%` is likely to be corrupted and certain other symbols (such as `&`) may also yield unexpected results. If the data is restricted to alphamerics, spaces, commas, etc. it should be fine.